# AWS Lambda function is timing out and only using 130 out of 3008 MB allocated. Why is it utilizing so little RAM?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, memory, aws-lambda

I have written a program in python(3.6) that iterates through a dataframe and calls 2 Rest APIs. It only takes the process about 6 minutes locally, but once uploaded to lambda, it runs for 15 minutes and then times out. It is only using 107 - 130 MB of memory each time and always times out. Can someone explain why this is occuring and a solution to fix this issue?

[image]

Comment: Timeout is related to time, not memory. What is your Lambda function doing? You could add some logging to see whether the delay is due to the external REST calls or local processing. As an experiment, try increasing the memory since this also increases the allocated CPU. For example, go real big, just to see whether it finishes. You can then reset it to a smaller size.

Comment: Sounds like it is failing to connect to one of the REST API endpoints and simply hanging and finally timing out. Is it running in VPC? Does it have a route to the API endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to monitor the type of usage your code needs(memory vs cpu). You could be being limited by the cpu power provided by lambda.

> Functions larger than 1536MB are allocated multiple CPU threads, and multi-threaded or multi-process code is needed to take advantage of the additional performance.

Comment: You need to cite the source you're quoting, here... but also, it's very unlikely that this is related.  The point of this statement is that *additional* CPU performance at memory allocations beyond 1536MB is only available to code that takes advantage of multiple cores.  At 1536 (or possibly 1792, depending on who's talking) you have exactly 1 vCPU available.